# Объемная тень для элемента.

Tags: css

Как лаконичнее можно сделать тень для элемента, чтобы он выглядел объемным? На данный момент я создаю отдельный элемент `.bottom-frame-shadow` задаю ему `background: $shadow-back;` и верхнюю границу, что сделать его объемным `border-top: 1px solid black;`. Можно ли сделать это как-то удобнее с помощью html или css?

```
$width-panel: 200px;
$radius-border: 7px;
$shadow-back: #441DBF;
$border: 2px solid black;

body {
  background: #6839FF;
    .panel {
      width: $width-panel;
      height: 200px;
      margin: 150px auto;
      border: $border;
      border-radius: $radius-border;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 $shadow-back;
      .inner-panel {
        background: grey;
        margin: 10px;
        width: 175px;
        height: 170px;
        border: $border;
        border-radius: $radius-border;
    }
      .bottom-frame-shadow {
        margin-top: 0px;
        padding-top: 5.5px;
        width: $width-panel;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        background: $shadow-back;
        border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
      }
  }
}


<div class='panel'>
  <div class='inner-panel'>
  </div>
  <div class='bottom-frame-shadow'>
  </div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZMerYB?editors=1100)

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так наверно ?

```css
.panel {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 150px auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 1px #555555, 3px 6px 1px #555555, 5px 7px 1px #555555, 7px 8px 1px #555555, 9px 9px 1px #ddd;
}

.inner-panel {
  background: grey;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 175px;
  height: 170px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.bottom-frame-shadow {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 5.5px;
  width: 200px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  background: #bbb;
  border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 1px #ddd, 3px 6px 1px #ddd, 5px 7px 1px #ddd, 7px 8px 1px #ddd, 9px 9px 1px #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class='panel'>
  <div class='inner-panel'>
  </div>
  <div class='bottom-frame-shadow'>
  </div>
</div>
```